# excel vba chart on a different sheet using that sheet's data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a program that creates a new sheet, adds data to that sheet, and the last part it should do is chart that output. When I try the code below, I get "object or variable or with block variable not set"

please let me know where I am going wrong. thank you.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select
   ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("J2", Sheets(ws.Name).Range("L2").End(xlDown).Address)
   ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
   With ActiveChart.Parent
   .Height = 400
   .Width = 800
   End With
Next
```

Comment: can you post the code where you set ws?

Comment: @vvba4all on this line       .       .        .ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("J2", Sheets(ws.Name).Range("L2").End(xlDown).Address)

Comment: @JimmySmith Thanks for helping. I added the rest of the code

Comment: @JimmySmith ws is assigned in the for each loop declaration

Answer (score 0):

You are using a comma to create your range with strings.  That only works with range objects.  Try:
`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("J2:" & ws.Range("L2").End((xlDown).Address)`

Comment: thanks, someone suggested that before, but it doesn't work. This statement works on activesheet, but doesn't work for another sheet

Answer (score 0):

```
With ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("J2", Sheets(ws.Name).Range("L2").End(xlDown).Address) 
.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
 End With
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation, why the `ActiveChart` variable is not set. Code only answers are generally disouraged.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of object accessors in vba return variant.
If you have this issues, for example chart.parent //returns variant btw
the first thing to try is to assign it to a typed variable
At run time if variant is dealt with as if it were a different type you will almost certainly get a runtime error.

```
dim ws As Worksheet
set ws = ActiveChart.Parent
With ws
    'ws operations here
    .Name = "My worksheet!"
    .Cells(1,1).Value = "cell A1"
End With
```

Also its worth noting that Workbook.Worksheets collection also contains the chart objects http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.worksheets.aspx

so when you are adding a chart a worksheet you are essentially adding to the collection you are iterating over which is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(ws.Name).Range("J2"), Sheets(ws.Name).Range("L2").End(xlDown))